# GameCube Games with Bonus Content on Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube

There are Gameboy games that offered bonus content when played on the Gameboy Advance like the Oracle series.

Are there GameCube games which offer additional content when run on Wii hardware

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't allow "Does X exist" questions, as they are basicly the same as game recommendation/identification questions. That being said, I highly doubt it. As far as I know, a GC-game run on a Wii doesn't know it's on Wii. As far as it's concerned, it's a GameCube it's being run on.

Comment: They aren't. If there is a technical reason for GameCube games running on Wii not to be able to detect the platform they're on, it is clearly answerable.

Comment: GameCube games can theoretically detect that they are being played on a Wii, as homebrew applications were used to gain access to Wii-specific protected data before homebrew in Wii mode was made possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As far as i know, no.**

None of the Gamecube games were made with the Wii in mind, so they didn't create any games having any special features on the Wii but not the Gamecube.
Since the Wii released there have only been very few games released for the gamecube aswell, i doubt anyone implemented something like that,

Comment: There are no games (that I've ever heard of) with extra content, however some that were released for both often play quite differently, such as Legend of Zelda: Twighlight Princess which has quite a few differences due to the game needing to be somewhat rebalanced for the Wiimote and Nunchuck control scheme. The most obvious difference is Link being left-handed (as he had been previously) in the GC version, and right-handed in the Wii version due to a majority right-handed playerbase.

Comment: @sequoiad that's a different matter altogether as the Wii version of Twilight Princess is actually a Wii game, not just a special GameCube game :P